# Debugging ASP.Net MVC in local IIS on Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am having issues debugging locally within Visual Studio 2010 on Server 2008 R2 (x64) for a new ASP.Net MVC application.  I am able to debug using the VS Development Server (Cassini) but when I change to use the Local IIS Web Server and Create Virtual Directory, I am unable to debug.  I get the standard VS message:

"Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The web server is not configured correctly. ..."

Everything looks standard in IIS.  The Default Web Site is running under the ASP.NET v4.0 application pool.  The virtual directory that Visual Studio created is running under the same app pool.  I am running Visual Studio as the Administrator account.  It feels like some security setting or something is preventing this to work but I'm at a loss to what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to run aspnet_regiis -i.